# Did Yagami Light take a risk while handing over the Death Note to Rem?

Tags: death-note

I didn't understand the scenario where Yagami Light relinquishes ownership of his Death Note for the first time.

He trusted Rem to give it to such a person who would have traits like that of Kyosuke Higuchi.

What if that plan had not worked? Didn't the entire plan hinge on Rem's choice of the person?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

People are predictable. Especially if you know one's personality in advance, you can almost accurately predict what one might do with great power, such as the Death Note.

Light is far from stupid, he knew exactly what would happen. He knew he'd use the Death Note to achieve a higher status, and that his and L's team would come and investigate. All a part of clearing their own name.

Basically, Light knew exactly what he was doing. Very little was left to chance in his plan.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. He did take a risk. But he knew his plan will all work, and it did. He knew how people will react and what he'll do next just basing with a person's personality because he is genius and smart (but he used it for bad acts, though). Think about it, he even knew what he'll do himself if he loses all of his memories about the Death Note and I guess knowing oneself is the most difficult thing to do, so judging and knowing what other people will do in a particular situation would be easier for him.